# ngOnDestroy not called when element is dynamically created with createComponent

Tags: angular

In my app I render components dynamically, like this

```
@ViewChild('container') c: ElementRef;

constructor(
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector,
    private envInjector: EnvironmentInjector
) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const ref = createComponent(FooComponent, {
      environmentInjector: this.envInjector,
      elementInjector: this.injector,
      hostElement: this.c.nativeElement,
  });

  this.appRef.attachView(ref.hostView);
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zqbdsl?file=src/app/foo/foo.component.ts)

The problem is that when this dynamic component gets destroyed, its `ngOnDestroy` function is no called (and not the ngOnDestroy of nested components). So I was wondering, is there something I'm missed or doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, 
Does your dynamic component disappear from the DOM when you destroy it?

Comment: It seems it's a bug in angular. Similar kind of issue they already closed:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/39365

Comment: Yes, I saw this one, but the components are created the old way. I will raise an new issue

Comment: Done, [bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/47315)